# bar plot cumulative data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot bars, with cumulative data

```
rects1 = ax.bar(0.02+ind,a, width2,color='k')
rects1a = ax.bar(0.02+ind, a2, width2, color='r',bottom=a)
rects1b = ax.bar(0.02+ind, a3, width2, color='b',bottom=a2)
rects1c = ax.bar(0.02+ind, a4, width2, color='g',bottom=a3)
rects1d= ...
```

`a`, `a2`, `a3`, etc are for instance 10%, 25%

I would like to have value `a4`, above `a3`, above `a2` above a
At the end, I have to obtain 100%

What do I have to change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `numpy.cumsum()`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html